# Embed images when converting from HTML with libreoffice

Tags: image, embed, libreoffice

I'm using libreoffice in headless mode to convert HTML into various formats.  For this question, we'll use docx for simplicity sake.

I use a command similar to this:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" --writer document.html
```

This works great for the most part.

The HTML includes a couple of absolute links to images.

```
<img src="http://myserver.com/image1.jpg" />
```

When the document is converted to document.docx, the images are still being linked to, not embedded into the document.  This causes problems when you're offline and in previews and such.

Is there a way that I can tell libreoffice to download and embed the images directly into the document instead of just keeping them as linked images?

Comment: I have the opposite problem.  The latest version seems to embed by default, but I'd like it to create actual files.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if libreoffice really converts to embed ones by default. If you aware of that, please comment here to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice currently (towards 6.3, but this is the situation since [this change](https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/23359) / 5.2) defaults to not embed images:

```
libreoffice --convert-to html test.odt
```

You can opt in to embed images like this:

```
libreoffice --convert-to html:'HTML (StarWriter):EmbedImages' test.odt
```

Answer (score -2):

To convert to odt it's pretty easy after installing pandoc.

After the relatively hard part: from odt (or even html) you can script (Open|Libre)Office via e.g. unoconv

Or you can like:

abiword --to=doc filename.odt
Also see this thread, and this blog post.
To convert to odt it's pretty easy after installing pandoc.

After the relatively hard part: from odt (or even html) you can script (Open|Libre)Office via e.g. unoconv

Or you can like:

abiword --to=doc filename.odt
Also see this thread, and this blog post.